# Dificuldades com algoritmo quickSort em C

Tags: c, quicksort

Preciso fazer um trabalho da faculdade envolvendo o quicksort, porém estou encontrando dificuldades no código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define RA 8

int quickSort(int *vec[], int left, int right, int qtd );
int partition(int *vec[], int left, int right);
void troca(int *x,int *y);

main(){
    int vet[RA] = {1,8,3,6,2,5,2,5};
    int left = 0;
    int right = left + 1;
    int qtd;

    printf("Antes do QuickSort: ");
    printf("\n[ ");
    for(int i = 0; i <= RA; i++){
        printf("%d ",vet[i]);
    }
    printf(" ]\n");

    quickSort(&vet[RA], left, right, qtd);
}

int quickSort(int vec[], int left, int right, int qtd){
    int r;
    if (right > left){
        r = partition(&vec,left,right);
        qtd = quickSort(&vec,left, r - 1, qtd);
        qtd = quickSort(&vec, r+1, right, qtd);
    }
    return (qtd + 1);
}

int partition(int *vec[], int left, int right){
    int i, j;
    i = left;
    for(j = left + 1; j <= right; j++){
        if(vec[j] < vec[left]){
            i++;
            troca(&vec[i], &vec[j]);
        }
    }
    troca(&vec[left],&vec[i]);
    return i;
}

void troca(int *x,int *y, int aux){
    aux = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = aux;
}
```

Me retorna os seguintes erros:

```
Estrutura 2.cpp In function 'int main()':

[Error] cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**' for argument '1' to 'int quickSort(int**, int, int, int)'

In function 'int partition(int**, int, int)':

[Error] cannot convert 'int**' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void troca(int*, int*)'

[Error] cannot convert 'int**' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void troca(int*, int*)'
```

Tenho a leve impressão que fiz algo de errado na passagem de parâmetros.

Comment: O que não entende? O que tentou para resolver a situação?

Comment: @MauroAlmeida os erros parecem chamar atenção para a passagem de parametros, porem quando modifico retorna mais erros.

Comment: Sabe a diferença entre endereços de memória e ponteiros? o Uso de '&' e '*'?

Comment: @MauroAlmeida o * vc vai estar acessando o conteudo da variavel na memoria, e o & vc esta indicando o endereço da variavel na memoria.

Comment: exato, é isso. O seu problema passa pela passagem de parâmetros como endereço no caso do array. O array já é um ponteiro para memória.

Comment: @MauroAlmeida sim ,mas aonde exatamente a passagem estaria errada?

Comment: Vc passa um endereço de memória para a function quicksort e coloca na assinatura do método que o parâmetro é um int *vec[], mas na implementação já coloca como int vec[].

Comment: para obter o valor do ponteiro tem de colocar * antes das variáveis que são ponteiros e não o *&*

Comment: entendeu o erro ou precisa de mais dicas? Não queria dar resposta, é melhor quando chegamos lá.

Comment: @MauroAlmeida Não, ainda não entendi mas estou analisando o código e realmente é melhor quando a solução estala na cabeça.

Comment: Outra coisa que não entendi é o número de parâmetros que a sua função de troca tem. A assinatura tem dois e a implementação tem 3. penso que a implementação com 3 parâmetros não faz sentido porque a variável auxiliar devia ser iniciada dentro do método e não como parâmetro.

Comment: E nas utilizações dessa função vc nunca coloca o terceiro parâmetro.

Comment: @MauroAlmeida como assim terceiro parametro?

Comment: Num lado você tem `int quickSort(int *vec[]` mas no outro tem `int quickSort(int vec[]` por isso o compilador não sabe qual você quer. E o mesmo para aqui `void troca(int *x,int *y)` que mais abaixo está assim `void troca(int *x,int *y, int aux)`.

Answer (score 0):

Código testa, abaixo alguns comentário das partes desnecessária do código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void troca(int x,int y){
  int aux;
    aux = x;
    x = y;
    y = aux;
}

int partition(int vec[], int left, int right){
    int i, j;
    i = left;
    for(j = left + 1; j <= right; j++){
        if(vec[j] < vec[left]){
            i++;
            troca(vec[i], vec[j]);
        }
    }
    troca(vec[left],vec[i]);
    return i;
}

int quickSort(int vec[], int left, int right, int qtd){
    int r;
    if (right > left){
        r = partition(vec,left,right);
        qtd = quickSort(vec,left, r - 1, qtd);
        qtd = quickSort(vec, r+1, right, qtd);
    }
    return (qtd + 1);
}

int main(){
    int vet[8] = {1,8,3,6,2,5,2,5};
    int left = 0;
    int right = left + 1;
    int qtd;

    printf("Antes do QuickSort: ");
    printf("\n[ ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        printf("%d ",vet[i]);
    }
    printf(" ]\n");

    quickSort(&vet[8], left, right, qtd);
}
```

Problemas encontrados:
1).No `for` da função principal deve-se ser `<` não `<=` pois imprimiria lixo de memoria.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= RA; i++){
    printf("%d ",vet[i]);
}
printf(" ]\n");
```

2). Você declarou as variáveis sem ponteiro, depois exigiu que tivessem nas funções que elas tivessem ponteiro.

```
int quickSort(int *vec[], int left, int right, int qtd );
int partition(int *vec[], int left, int right);
void troca(int *x,int *y);
```

3).A colocação de `&` dentro da função `quicksort`,`partition` e :

```
qtd = quickSort(&vec,left, r - 1, qtd);
        qtd = quickSort(&vec, r+1, right, qtd);
```

//

```
for(j = left + 1; j <= right; j++){
        if(vec[j] < vec[left]){
            i++;
            troca(&vec[i], vec[j]);
        }
    }
    troca(&vec[left],vec[i]);
```